# I'd like to have my lower boundary as -infinity but it will only have one character

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass{article}      
\title{Latex exercice}  
\author{ME}  

\begin{document}  
\maketitle % showing both title and author, plus date  
\begin{equation}  
  \Gamma(x)=\int_\infty^\infty dt    
  \Gamma(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt  
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you mean, but maybe you need `\int_{-\infty}`?

Comment: Or `\int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}` for a better optical appeareance, but that's a matter of taste. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: your code should be  \Gamma(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt

Comment: @qwerty314 In (almost) any command, if you need more than one token in one place, surrounding them by braces works. Moreover, in cases where more than one token is possible, even if you only need one, it's recommended to have `{}` around the argument (e.g., `\frac a 2` should be written as `\frac{a}{2}`).

Comment: @egreg If subscripts and superscripts are always braced, it should be `$\int_{0}^{1} x^{2}\,dx$`. `:-)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Precisely so!

Comment: If you look at the LaTeX manual, you'll find that subscripts and superscripts are always braced, like in `$\int_{0}^{1} x^{2}\,dx$`; putting braces is never wrong, omitting them might produce puzzling results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the math in this example (as in the MWE) is *wrong*, in the sense that the result defines no `x` (unless it's meant to be constant `x`-function), they represent two methods for typesetting the `-\infty` symbols as the lower bound.

In order to get both symbols, `-\infty` and `\infty`, together as a lower integral limit, it's necessary to group both symbols within a `{}` pair, i.e.

```
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}
```

For better visual appeal, one could use `\int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}`.

The differential symbol `dt` should be typeset with an upright `d`

I added a command `\showniceint` which typesets the nice form of `int` automatically with an upright `d` as well as a short version for integrals from `-\infty` to `\infty`.

The first argument is optional and defaults to a standard `x`, such that integration is over x.

```
\documentclass{article}      
\title{Latex exercice}  
\author{By ME}  

\newcommand{\showniceint}[4][x]{%
  \int\limits^{#3}_{#2}\left({#4}\right)\mathrm{d}#1%
}%

% Short version for integrals from -\infty to \infty
\newcommand{\showniceinftyint}[2][x]{%
  \showniceint[#1]{-\infty}{\infty}{#2}%
}%


\begin{document}  
\maketitle % showing both title and author, plus date  
\begin{equation}  
  \Gamma(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt  \label{first} 
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
  \Gamma(x) = \int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mathrm{d}t \label{second}  
\end{equation}  

\begin{equation}
  \Gamma(x) = \showniceint[t]{-\infty}{\infty}{1} \label{third}
\end{equation}  

\begin{equation}
  \Gamma(x) = \showniceinftyint[t]{1} \label{fourth}
\end{equation}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This once more shows why it's better to teach *always* bracing superscripts and subscripts.

Comment: The upright "d" (`\mathrm{d}`) isn't the standard everywhere. `;-)`

Comment: @1010011010: I don't care ;-)